# TeXnicCenter - Forward search issue

Tags: texniccenter, forward-inverse-search

I have been facing this intermittent problem with TeXnicCenter [TC] forward search.

[image: error window]

I have gone through many posts in [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions) and I have followed what is to be done. It works at times and at times NOT. I am not able to figure out the root cause of the problem.

**My configuration for build in [TXC] is as follows:**

- Exec path

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]'\""`
- View project output

  `DDE Command[sumatra, control]` - `[Open("%bm.pdf",0,1,1)]`
- Fwd search

  `DDE command[sumatra, control]` - `[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]`
- close document before running LaTeX

  Do not close.

**Screenshot**:

[image: profile window]

Comment: At content: There is one `'` too much, and I would add double quotes, because you have spaces in the path. So try out: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""`. Also a suggestion: Add the option `-reuse-instance`, then the open window is reused.

Comment: It works fine the first run , but the second run onward it starts giving me the same error. I have never faced this before. Not sure why its random. The new exec path is : `"C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""`

Comment: Then I cannot help anymore. This sounds to me like a strange user right issue, though: Opening allowed, but not updating the windows content.

Comment: Now its even worse. When I compile (`CTRL+F5`) or (`CTRL+SHIFT+F5`) the TeXnicCenter compiles -> Opens Sumatra -> Gets stuck ... It doesnt even show the final PDF output on sumatra. Its like its compiling for ever.

Comment: Then your error or mistake must be somewhere else and is a local issue, because everything works fine here. You could try to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, _and post this in a new question_. It will be much easier for others to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when they see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112703/texniccenter-crashes-on-build-and-view-output

Comment: I have one last idea: Download the ZIP version of SumatraPDF (containing only the executable) and_put this in a folder outside of `C:\Program Files`, let’s say for testing in `C:\SumatraPDF` or in `C:\LaTeX\SumatraPDF`. Then change the according path in TXC and try again.

Comment: @Speravir: No that dint work either. I really appreciate all the help you guys are providing me. The truth is it happened all of sudden. I worked the same file on my other laptop and it works just fine. So there is a real problem with my system.

Comment: I have the same issue. It is very intermittent, happens about once in 100 compiles.