# TeXnicCenter Crashes on BUILD and VIEW OUTPUT

Tags: pdf, miktex, texniccenter

This is in reference to [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112463/texniccenter-forward-search-issue) that I have posted and dint get it resolved.

**PROBLEM** : BUILD CURRENT FILE on TXC works Fine. BUILD AND VIEW OUTPUT or VIEW OUTPUT makes TXC to open sumatra and crash ( compiles for ever ). Have to force stop sumatra from task manager.

its not local to any file. It happens to every file.

Example :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\author{abhi}  

\title{Simple Document}

\begin{document}  

HELLO WORLD ! THIS IS AN EXAMPLE ! 

\end{document}
```

Below is the image of the LaTex and BibTeX result in TXC.

[image]

But this compiles and gives output just fine in TeXworks that comes with MiKTEX.

If someone would try to help me resolve this issue I sure would appreciate it.

Comment: Kind request: If your two questions are related don't post as different instead add an **EDIT: Update on ....** to existing Q. I don't use TeXnic Center but may be viewer configuration might be a problem. Have a look at [Configure TexnicCenter with something else than Adobe Reader X](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12500/15717).

Comment: @texenthusiast See my last comment to the linked question …

Comment: I was asked to repost it as a new quesiton with a MWE. Therefore I posted a new question. But I will follow your suggestion from next post. Thank you @texenthusiast

Comment: @Speravir Ok sorry hence "If"

Comment: @abhilashsukumari This runs OK on my side with TeXnicCenter and Adobe Reader.  This is most likely due to your pdf reader, and texenthusiast link should give you a hint on how to fix it

Comment: Seeing this you could have edited into the other question, I must confess. I see also, that `makeindex` is complaining, because there is nothing to do for it, but on my machine this will not lead to such problems. So once again: I think you have a problem originated in your OS.

Comment: @MarioS.E. No problem at all here with TXC and SumatraPDF, so the same combination like OP has.

Comment: Ok. If thats the case I am gonna try the same project/file on my lab computer and update you on the result.

Comment: TeXniccenter related Questions and Answers [Unable to generate pdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111967/15717). BTW are you using TC2 beta 1 ? You will certainly resolve it with some patience meanwhile if you are with deadlines work on TeXworks.

Comment: Yes. I am thinking to switch editors.

Comment: \maketitle after \begin{document}?